# How do I pass a managed array to a function?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am trying to write a Tic-Tac-Toe game but I'm getting compiler errors. There are 3 errors related to the `TTT::whoWins` function. Can anyone help me and or point me in the right direction.

Errors are:

```
Error 2 error C2664: 'TTT::checkColumn' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' to 'int [][3]' C:\Users\Grunt\Desktop\tictactoe game\tictactoe game\TTT.cpp 59
Error 3 error C2664: 'TTT::checkDiagonal' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' to 'int [][3]' C:\Users\Grunt\Desktop\tictactoe game\tictactoe game\TTT.cpp 59
Error 1 error C2664: 'TTT::checkRow' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' to 'int [][3]' C:\Users\Grunt\Desktop\tictactoe game\tictactoe game\TTT.cpp 59
```

Code appears below:

```
TTT::TTT()
{
    matrix = gcnew array <int,2>(3,3);
}

bool TTT::isaTie()
{
    return 0;
}

bool TTT::isaTie2()
{
    return 0;
}

int TTT::whoWins()
{

    if((checkRow(matrix,ROW_SIZE))==1 || (checkColumn(matrix,COLUMN_SIZE))==1 || (checkDiagonal(matrix,ROW_SIZE))==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}


bool TTT::checkRow (int mat[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE)
{
    int row1 = mat[0][0] + mat[0][1] + mat [0][2];
    int row2 = mat[1][0] + mat[1][1] + mat [1][2];
    int row3 = mat[2][0] + mat[2][1] + mat [2][2];

    if (row1 == 0 || row2 == 0 || row3 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (row1 == 3 || row2 == 3 || row3 == 3)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
bool TTT::checkColumn (int mat[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE)
{
    int col1 = mat[0][0] + mat[1][0] + mat [2][0];
    int col2 = mat[0][1] + mat[1][1] + mat [2][1];
    int col3 = mat[0][2] + mat[1][2] + mat [2][2];

    if (col1 == 0 || col2 == 0 || col3 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (col1 == 3 || col2 == 3 || col3 == 3)
    {
        return 1;
    }else
        return 0;
}

bool TTT::checkDiagonal (int mat[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE)
{
    int diag1 = mat[0][0] + mat[1][1] + mat [2][2];
    int diag2 = mat[2][0] + mat[1][1] + mat [0][2];

    if (diag1 == 0 || diag2 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (diag1 == 3 || diag2 == 3)
    {
        return 1;
    }else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class `matrix` is of type `array` but in your functions (e.g. `checkRow`) your first argument is of type `int`. So you would need to change this into `array`.

On the other hand your check* functions are part of TTT, so they can access matrix directly and don't need it as argument.

Comment: I attempted it and its just giving me even more errors. Are you able to give me more detailed information please?

Comment: I suggest you read: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7704/Arrays-in-C-CLI that should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert enough to know how to do that, but I learnt that a way is to make another array of pointers and link it with the array, and use it instead of using the array directly. Another way is to declare the arrays globally. To declare the array globally it has not to be in any function, and to declare an array of int it would be like (int * x[10]) for example.

I hope that was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are having trouble with is realizing that a CLI gc object such as array^ is not at all the same as a C++ style array.  You can't interchange them.  They are laid out completely differently and any CLI type sits in moveable memory, has certain methods, etc whereas a C++ array is just a block of memory.  In C++/CLI you have the choice of using either type of object, but since you seemed to wait to use the gc object, I've edited your code to use it, below.  The syntax is a little different, you use array^ as your function parameters (reference to a 2D array of int).  Then you address the array with CLI-style indexing such as [0,1] not [0][1] as you would use in C++.  Not sure why you had ROW_SIZE and COLUMN_SIZE since you didn't use them so I removed them.

```
public ref class TTT
{
public:
    array<int, 2>^ matrix;

TTT::TTT()
{
    matrix = gcnew array <int,2>(3, 3);
}

bool TTT::isaTie()
{
    return 0;
}

bool TTT::isaTie2()
{
    return 0;
}

int TTT::whoWins()
{
    if ((checkRow(matrix))==1 || (checkColumn(matrix))==1 || (checkDiagonal(matrix))==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}


bool TTT::checkRow(array<int, 2>^ mat)
{
    int row1 = mat[0,0] + mat[0,1] + mat[0,2];
    int row2 = mat[1,0] + mat[1,1] + mat[1,2];
    int row3 = mat[2,0] + mat[2,1] + mat[2,2];

    if (row1 == 0 || row2 == 0 || row3 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (row1 == 3 || row2 == 3 || row3 == 3)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
bool TTT::checkColumn (array<int, 2>^ mat)
{
    int col1 = mat[0,0] + mat[1,0] + mat[2,0];
    int col2 = mat[0,1] + mat[1,1] + mat[2,1];
    int col3 = mat[0,2] + mat[1,2] + mat[2,2];

    if (col1 == 0 || col2 == 0 || col3 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (col1 == 3 || col2 == 3 || col3 == 3)
    {
        return 1;
    }else
        return 0;
}

bool TTT::checkDiagonal (array<int, 2>^ mat)
{
    int diag1 = mat[0,0] + mat[1,1] + mat[2,2];
    int diag2 = mat[2,0] + mat[1,1] + mat[0,2];

    if (diag1 == 0 || diag2 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (diag1 == 3 || diag2 == 3)
    {
        return 1;
    }else
        return 0;
}

};
```